# Kubernetes external probes

Tags: kubernetes

Is it possible to define external path for example a other webserver as path for the web probes?
Or a TCP probe with a different IP?

```
        livenessProbe:
          httpGet:
            path: external.de/test
            port: 8080
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 10
```

I know thats not how you should use probes but I need it for testing.
Does someone know how to define probes that are not applied on the pods directly?

Answer (score 2):

You can use following command along with your liveness probe

```
livenessProbe:
  exec:
    command:
    - curl
    - external.de/test:8080
  initialDelaySeconds: 10
  periodSeconds: 105
```

In this case, if `curl external.de/test:8080`command returns with an exit code of **0** then it will be assumed healthy, otherwise any other exit code will be deemed unhealthy.

Also keep in mind, once probe will fail, the pod running this probe will be restarted, not the one that running `external.de/test:8080` web server

More details on how to use command within liveness probe described [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-probes/#define-a-liveness-command)

Comment: This is good but keep in mind that curl should be installed on the container image: this doesn't work if you're using a `from scratch` Docker image

Answer (score 1):

If you want to achieve that, you cannot use the *http* probe.

You have to use the *exec* one, pointing to a simple bash script that executes cURL on your behalf, so you can mount it via a *ConfigMap* or directly *hostMount* to perform your testing.